# Return value from Webmethod and Alert at javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, webmethod

I tried to alert numberOfHours in javascript ajax which is from WebMethod.
I am not so sure how to retrieve value from WebMethod and parse it to ajax for alert message.

Below here is webmethod and ajax that I am working on  :

//WebMethod aspx.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetFirstDateAndLastDate(DateTime firstDayDate, DateTime lastDayDate,string ddlName)
    {
        //String daresult = null;
        string firstDay = firstDayDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        string lastDay = lastDayDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        //testing purpose only
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT sum([NumberOfHours]) FROM [LoginDB1].[dbo].[tbOT] where [Date] between '" + firstDay + "' And  '" + lastDay + "' AND name =  + '" + ddlName + "'", conn);
        //say for example numberOfhours get  "9.0" hours from sql

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dt);

        //trying with arraylist but not able to return
       // ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();           
        //foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
       // rows.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => 
        item.ToString())));


        return "OK";
    }
```

//Script aspx

```
                 var selectedDate = $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker('getDate');

                            var firstDay = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), 1);
                            var lastDay = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);                 

                            var data = {};
                            data.firstDayDate =firstDay.getFullYear() + "-" + (firstDay.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + firstDay.getDate();      
                            data.lastDayDate = lastDay.getFullYear() + "-" + (lastDay.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + lastDay.getDate();                          
                            data.ddlName = $("[id$=ddlName] option:selected").text();
                            console.log("Log Data", data)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "SupervisorOTRequest.aspx/GetFirstDateAndLastDate",                                  
                                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",                                   

                                     success: function (response) {

                                    if (response.d == "OK") {

                                          //alert return value                  

                                    }                                   

                            });
```

Kindly Advise and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please advise what the problem with your code is.

Comment: @John...No error in my coding.It just I want to return value from webmethod to ajax as alert message only.

Comment: I didn't mean error, I meant what here is stopping you from achieving your goal?

Comment: @John, simply I just can't get alert value (numberOfhours get  "9.0" ) from javascript.
And I got no idea how to retrieve from webmethods to ajax

Comment: Well, at the moment you're returning "OK" on the server, so that is your return value. If you want to return a different value, you can do so. HTTP indicates success/failure as status codes.

Comment: you should alert(response) i don't think there is any reason for using response.d